# Bluetooth 4.0 generic mouse pointer not moving

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, mouse

I was on Ubuntu 22.04 lts and the bluetooth mouse was working fine.
It works on Windows 11.
I made a fresh installation with Ubuntu 22.04.3 lts to have my 12th generation chips works with my two monitors.
The mouse connects but the pointer, buttons and scroll wheel are not working.
Mouse disconnects after 30 seconds since there is no move.
Tried to reinstall bluez with no success (version on computer is 5.64-0ubuntu1).
The battery is new.

Comment: Get more information with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0 bluez`.